# Yup validate password contains at least one special character

Tags: regex, reactjs, yup

I am using the following yup:

```
export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  password: Yup.string()
    .required('Password is required')
    .matches(
      /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/,
      'Need one special character',
    ),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string()
    .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
    .required('Password confirm is required'),
});
```

to validate if there is one special character in password string.

```
@ => valid
@a => invalid
a@ => invalid
aa => invalid, of course
```

I also test the regex pattern online to make sure this pattern will catch any special character in string
I wonder it could be yup bug or I do something wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try using the following regex pattern:

```
^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?].*$
```

This just matches any input so long as it has a special character.  Your updated React code:

```
export const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    password: Yup.string()
       .required('Password is required')
       .matches(
           /^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?].**$/,
          'Need one special character',
       ),
   confirmPassword: Yup.string()
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
    .required('Password confirm is required'),
});
```

Comment: This work for me in vue3: /^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?].*$/

Answer (score 5):

You can try the below regex:

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?][0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Matches start and end of the given string resp.
>
> **`[0-9A-Za-z]*`** - Matches any character in the given range **zero or more times.**
>
> **`[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]`** - Matches exactly one special character among the given set.

You can find the regex demo [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/rYT2yE/1)

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add pattern to match any character before and after special character.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! Extremely helpful.